# How do I set the end date of a jQuery ui datepicker calendar to the users start date please?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm new to Javascript and would appreciate some help with my jQuery datepicker code, please. I've spent ages looking on here and trying to fix my code but just can't seem to get it to work...I would like the user to select the start date and then when they click on the end date, they can only choose dates from the start date onwards. I also need to calculate the number of days (but I have done this and its working).

Heres the script code:

```
function showDays() {
    var start = $('#startDate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#endDate').datepicker('getDate');

    if (!start || !end) return;
    var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
    $('#noDays').val(days);
    if (days > 15) {
    alert ( "The maximum amount of nights is 15. Please select dates within this range." )
    $( '#endDate' ).focus();
  }
    document.getElementById("p__myTrip--days").innerHTML =  days;
  }
$("#startDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    minDate: 0,
    changeMonth: true,
    onSelect: showDays,
     onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
         var dParts = selectedDate.split('-');
         var in30Days = new Date(dParts[2] + '/' +
                        dParts[1] + '/' +
                        (+dParts[0] + 30)
               );     
    $("#endDate").datepicker("option", "minDate");
    }
});
$("#endDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    setDate: '#startDate',
    onSelect: showDays
});
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you! :)

Comment: Why not use jquery **date range picker** ? Check out [here](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$("#endDate").datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    setDate: '#startDate',
    endDate: '#endDate',
    onSelect: showDays
});
```

Comment: Thank you @ Shahnewaz :)